# Transferring javascript array to php

Tags: javascript, php, html

On my website the user will choose an array of boxes, then when they click submit the array will be sent to the database, so you can see on this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2peL8qg8/

However, in the php file I get the error: Invalid index and invalid argument for foreach(). Please could someone tell me why? Thanks

HTML and Javascript:

```
<form action="addtodatabase.php" method="post" id="theform">
<input type="hidden" id="markers" name="markers">
<button>Submit</button>
</form>

</body>


<script type="text/javascript">


var points = [];

window.onload = window.onresize = function() {
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth * 0.8;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight * 0.8;
}


function getSquare(canvas, evt) {
var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
return {
    x: 1 + (evt.clientX - rect.left) - (evt.clientX - rect.left)%10,
    y: 1 + (evt.clientY - rect.top) - (evt.clientY - rect.top)%10
};
}

function drawGrid(context) {
for (var x = 0.5; x < 10001; x += 10) {
  context.moveTo(x, 0);
  context.lineTo(x, 10000);
}

for (var y = 0.5; y < 10001; y += 10) {
  context.moveTo(0, y);
  context.lineTo(10000, y);
}

context.strokeStyle = "#ddd";
context.stroke();
}

function fillSquare(context, x, y){
context.fillStyle = "black"
context.fillRect(x,y,9,9);
points.push(x+","+y);
for (var i=points.length;i--;){

}
}

var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

drawGrid(context);

canvas.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
 var mousePos = getSquare(canvas, evt);
fillSquare(context, mousePos.x, mousePos.y)
}, false);


var myDataObj = new Object();
myDataObj.points = points;

$.ajax({  
type: "POST",
url: "localhost/website/addtodatabase.php",
data: JSON.stringify(myDataObj),
contentType: "application/json"
});
```

php

```
$sql = "Insert into MYTABLE (Point,UserName) VALUES (?,?)";
$db =new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=box;","root","");
$sth = $db->prepare($sql);
foreach($myPoints as $point)
{
  $sth->execute(array($point,$username));
}
```

Comment: Add var_dump($_POST);exit(); to the top of your PHP.  To see what data is being posted to your Web server.

Comment: It seems like you are referencing variables that haven't been declared ($myPoints, $point, $username)?

Answer (score 0):

This Function should be called by your submit button.  Currently you have that javascript executing right away.

```
function PostDataToServer()
{
  var myDataObj = new Object();
  myDataObj.points = points;

  $.ajax({  
    type: "POST",
    url: "localhost/website/addtodatabase.php",
    data: JSON.stringify(myDataObj),
    contentType: "application/json"
  });
}
```

and your save button should be like:

```
<input id="saveBtn" type="button" value="Save" onclick="PostDataToServer();" />
```

then you should do this in your addtodatabase.php

```
<?php
//Lets dump the post data back to the screen to make
//sure we are actually getting the data
//::TODO:: comment the var_dump($_POST); after verifying your getting data
var_dump($_POST);

$myPoints = json_decode($_POST['points']);
$sql = "Insert into MYTABLE (Point,UserName) VALUES (?,?)";
$db =new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=box;","root","");
$sth = $db->prepare($sql);
if(count($myPoints)>0)
{
   foreach($myPoints as $point)
   {
     $sth->execute(array($point,$username));
   }
}
else
{
   echo 'No Points were set in the array $myPoints';
}
```

Also add jquery to your js

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Hey, it seems I get Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined in the javascript/html file when I click save. I'm using localhost

Comment: In your head tag add jquery  <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

Comment: @PHPDave Just a suggestion, take it for what you will, the use of the `onclick` attribute is unnecessary ... In the spirit of improving each other's skills, and the craft in general, please see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript

Comment: @MichaelStilson Yea I would of done a jQuery .on(), but for simplicity sake, and because this guy appears new, something simple as onclick seems like a good fit.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle

Comment: @PHPDave :) indeed sir. I would argue both our chosen aspirations go hand-in-hand. Thanks for the feedback. Take care.

Comment: Thanks Mike you too!  Hard to figure out how advance of a solution to provide to people.